# Move a NIC to another PCIe slot

Tags: nic, pci-express

I have a server running OpenSuse with a 10Gbe card (Intel 82599eb) and the driver is installed and it is working correctly.

I need to move the card to another slot. However, when I do so, the card no longer comes up. By that I mean, it does not show up when I run an `lspci`. I've read that you might have to set a flag in the bios for data interrupts.

Found a thread on OpenSuse forums (http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/484833-moving-nic-different-pci-slot-problem.html) that says:

> There is a BIOS setting to reset the data for interrupts so it
>   discovers the new location of the card. Should be something like
>   "Reset Configuration Data" change this to yes and reboot

I went into the bios and cannot seem to find anything that sounds like that. Its a Tyan server if that helps. Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Getting it seen in LSPCI is one thing but also in addition be aware of Consistent Network Device Naming. i.e. the device name may change: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming

Comment: Some Motherboards require both or all processors to be installed in order to utilize all the slots.  Supermicro boxes do this for instance.  Might be best to consult the manual that came with the motherboard to verify this is or isn't the case..

Answer (score 1):

If the card does not show under the lspci command, you most likely have a dead PCIe slot.

Do you have any other PCIe cards you can test in the slot?